# Event when Spark transtion ends not getting sent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am trying to get notification of when a Spark transition begins and ends. According to the Adobe docs for the [ViewTransitionBase](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/transitions/ViewTransitionBase.html#event:transitionEnd), I should be able to do this.

I've tried adding event listeners to my component, to the `Parallel` instance and to the `Resize` effect but never receive any events.

Am I doing this wrong or are these events only possible if the transitions are wholly created in AS3? There is a note on the link above: *"Create and configure view transitions in ActionScript; you cannot create them in MXML."* – but obviously I can create the transitions in MXML - they work fine - and I am able to add event listeners - so what gives?

```
myResize.addEventListener(FlexEvent.TRANSITION_END, onTransitionEnd);
myResize.addEventListener(FlexEvent.TRANSITION_START, onTransitionStart);
```

---

```
    <s:states>
    <s:State name="window"/>
    <s:State name="fullscreen"/>
</s:states>

<s:transitions>
    <!-- zoom transition from/to each state -->
    <s:Transition id="myTransition" fromState="*" toState="*">
        <s:Parallel id="zoomer" targets="{[this]}">
            <s:Move  duration="300" autoCenterTransform="true"/>
            <s:Resize id="myResize" duration="300" />
        </s:Parallel>
    </s:Transition>
</s:transitions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried adding events to Spark transitions and It worked very well. I think that the problem is may be in your code.

Take this example : [Adobe.com : simple transition](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fae.html), I edited to add events :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="400" creationComplete="init(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.events.EffectEvent

            private const newline:String = String.fromCharCode(13)

            private function init(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                resize_effect.addEventListener(EffectEvent.EFFECT_START, function(e:EffectEvent):void
                {
                    set_log_text('resize effect : start')
                })
                resize_effect.addEventListener(EffectEvent.EFFECT_END, function(e:EffectEvent):void
                {
                    set_log_text('resize effect : end')
                })
            }               

            private function move_effect_start_handler(e:EffectEvent):void
            {
                set_log_text('move effect : start')

            }
            private function move_effect_end_handler(e:EffectEvent):void 
            {
                set_log_text('move effect : end')

            }

            private function set_log_text(txt:String):void 
            {                   
                txt_log.text += newline + txt

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- Define the two view states, in addition to the base state.-->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="default"/>
        <s:State name="One"/>
        <s:State name="Two"/>
    </s:states>

    <!-- Define Transition array with one Transition object.-->
    <s:transitions>
        <!-- A transition for changing from any state to any state. -->
        <s:Transition id="myTransition" fromState="*" toState="*">
            <!-- Define a Parallel effect as the top-level effect.-->
            <s:Parallel id="t1" targets="{[p1,p2,p3]}">
                <!-- Define a Move and Resize effect.-->
                <s:Move  duration="400" effectStart="move_effect_start_handler(event)" effectEnd="move_effect_end_handler(event)" />
                <s:Resize duration="400" id="resize_effect"/>
            </s:Parallel>
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>

    <!-- Define the container holding the three Panel containers.-->
    <s:Group id="pm" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Panel id="p1" title="One" 
                 x="0" y="0" 
                 x.One="110" y.One="0" 
                 x.Two="0" y.Two="0" 
                 width="100" height="100"
                 width.One="200" height.One="210"
                 width.Two="100" height.Two="100"
                 click="currentState='One'">
            <s:Label fontSize="24" text="One"/>
        </s:Panel>

        <s:Panel id="p2" title="Two" 
                 x="0" y="110" 
                 x.One="0" y.One="0" 
                 x.Two="110" y.Two="0" 
                 width="100" height="100"
                 width.One="100" height.One="100"
                 width.Two="200" height.Two="210"
                 click="currentState='Two'">
            <s:Label fontSize="24" text="Two"/>
        </s:Panel>

        <s:Panel id="p3" title="Three" 
                 x="110" y="0" 
                 x.One="0" y.One="110" 
                 x.Two="0" y.Two="110" 
                 width="200" height="210" 
                 width.One="100" height.One="100" 
                 width.Two="100" height.Two="100" 
                 click="currentState='default'">
            <s:Label fontSize="24" text="Three"/>
        </s:Panel>
        <s:TextArea id="txt_log" includeIn="default,One,Two" x="28" y="237" width="330" height="300" />
    </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks for taking the time. The fault is in my code (and perhaps my stars... with this project). I wasn't listening for the `EffectEvent`event – and hadn't even come across a mention of that in any of my searches.